# Why does my terminal in VS Code have weird spacing and how can I fix it?

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal, fonts

This is what my settings is looking like:

[image: This is what my settings is looking like]

This is the weird spacing between letters in terminal:

[image: This is the weird spacing between letters in terminal]

Why is the font on my VS Code's terminal have this weird spacing between letters? It is really bugging me and I tried to change the font in the settings to a monospace font (inconsolata), but that hasn't worked.

Comment: Try tweaking the `Terminal > Integrated: Letter Spacing` setting to see if it helps.

Comment: None of the answers give useful analysis.  The problem is that the chosen font is not a fixed-pitch font.  Most terminals will use the width of the widest character in the font to simplify the layout in this case.

Answer (score 15):

I think those big spaces between the characters comes from your *exotic* chosen font (Inconsolata). So change only `"terminal.integrated.fontFamily": "Inconsolata"` back to the default font:

```
"terminal.integrated.fontFamily": "Monaco"
```

And look, to need the double-quote, and not some *triple quote* like in your screenshot!

Comment: I got the strange terminal although I did not choose a fontfamily in settings of VScode. I added the recommended fontfamily 'monaco' and the strangeness vanished.

Answer (score 9):

This usually happens when the chosen font is not installed on your system. Try to revert the font settings by removing or commenting these two lines:

```json
"terminal.integrated.fontFamily": "Inconsolata"
"Editor.fontFamily": "Source Code pro"
```

The default font is usually the default monospace font of your system.

Comment: **THAT'S THE SOLUTION!** The others are mere workarounds. The actual problem when this happens is that the font is not installed on the system and therefore idk why VsCode goes mad. I had in my `settings.json`: `"editor.fontFamily": "'Fantasque Sans Mono', 'Source Code Pro', 'Fira Code'"`. As soon as i **installed** "Fantasque Sans Mono" and **restarted** vscode everything went back to normal. Now the terminal looks as expected.

Answer (score 3):

Using "MesloLGS Nerd Font Mono 11" as the integrated terminal family font fixed this issue.

[image]

Don't forget to make sure it is the integrated terminal family font you're setting and not the editor's family font.

Answer (score 1):

VS Code only accepts unicode fonts.

Try to setup:

```
"terminal.integrated.fontFamily": "monospace"
```

Answer (score 0):

This was occurring for me using GitHub CodeSpaces.  I used the path File - Preferences - Settings - typed terminal font family in the search and basically blanked out the name of the font so nothing was in the box.