# VSCode terminal with buggy font

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal

Well, I have installed vscode to my job laptop and for some reason, the font of its integrated terminal is weird A LOT. Take a look at this screenshot:

[image: vscode integrated terminal]

So, as you can see, the font there is really weird and I have no idea what has happened. The settings are synced with my personal laptop vscode and it's normal there.

PS.: The font of the windows CMD and PS are OK, nothing wrong with them.

What can be causing that?

Comment: Try some setting for the terminal letter-spacing setting.  That might fix it.

Comment: There are settings like `terminal.integrated.fontFamily` out there to control the rendering, https://halfblood.pro/powershell-on-macos/ so you should review those settings and see what exactly are the values configured.

Comment: it does not look like a monospace font used (Times Roman)

Comment: apparently there is no `terminal` entry for the settings file here, it is not recognized. Also, shouldn't the terminal on my job laptop be synced with my personal laptop? I mean, the integrated terminal, since everything in my VSCode is synced.

Comment: I'm out of close votes. duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70856163/why-does-my-terminal-in-vs-code-have-weird-spacing-and-how-can-i-fix-it

Answer (score 0):

I faced this very problem when starting on windows. In my case, this issue was caused by syncing my user settings for Mac which has "editor.fontFamily": "Monaco" for the editor font family. Resetting this field to default value solve the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

It happens when the font you set for `terminal.integrated.fontFamily` doesn't exist anymore in your system (Windows or Mac).

You'll want to either:

- Search "terminal font" in settings
- Change the font family with the one exist

Alternatively, it may caused by `editor.fontFamily` with the same reasons.