# Spacing between characters in the VSCode terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal

My VSCode terminal text is like this, how can it be fixed?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does my terminal in VS Code have weird spacing and how can I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70856163/why-does-my-terminal-in-vs-code-have-weird-spacing-and-how-can-i-fix-it)

Comment: This is my question, but none of the answers solve my problem |:

Comment: If it's the same question and you're just waiting for an answer, don't ask a new duplicate question. See [/help/no-one-answers](/help/no-one-answers).

Answer (score 0):

Try this first:
Use split screen in the terminal window i.e. 2 terminals visible.
Restart VS Code and it boots with one terminal visible only and with crazy letter spacing.
to fix i just click split screen again and all is fine.

If it doesn't work you can edit `"editor.letterSpacing"` setting.

for example:

```
{
    "editor.letterSpacing": -0.15
}
```

Comment: Instead of answering this duplicate question, why not answer [the original question](/q/70856163/)?