# How can I restore default terminal appearance in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

When using Visual Studio Code on Windows 10, I encountered an issue where the terminal's font was messed up. There's a space between each letter, rendering the terminal very difficult to read. When I uninstalled VS Code entirely, and re-installed it, the issue persisted. How can I reset the user settings for VS Code back to default settings?

[image: issue with spacing in Terminal]

Comment: Looks a lot like when I had a misspelled font name in the configs somewhere, try changing the font for the console.

Comment: potential dup of https://stackoverflow.com/q/70856163/11107541

Answer (score 0):

**Cause of the issue**

I discovered that this issue is caused by the editor font being set to a non-monospace font. Setting the editor font will extend that font to the terminal as well, and VS Code doesn't appear to support terminal fonts that are non-monospace, i.e. Arial. This resulted in the terminal outputting the results in a very strange way.

**Resetting VS Code terminal appearance, and other settings**

To fix the primary issue, I went into preferences (Ctrl + , on windows), and searched for 'Editor Font', and changed it to a monospace font: Courier New. This fixed the issue. I wanted to also reset VS Code back to default settings, as this was a brand new install after having uninstalled and re-installed.

There are two ways to reset Visual Studio Code back to default settings:

1. Clear the user settings file. This is the easiest way to reset all of your settings to the default values. The user settings file is located at %APPDATA%\Code\User\settings.json on Windows. You can open this file in a text editor and delete everything between the two curly braces {}. Once you have saved the file, VS Code will restart and all of your settings will be reset.

   [image: settings.json file after reset]
2. Use the Reset All Settings command. This command will reset all of your settings to the default values, including your extensions, workspaces, and keybindings. To use this command, open the Command Palette (Ctrl+Shift+P) and type Reset All Settings. Then, press Enter to execute the command.

Comment: weird. so the `terminal.integrated.fontFamily` setting had nothing to do with your problem?

Comment: @starball I'm on Linux and I'm pretty sure I accidentally hit **`alt`+`z`** *(Toggle size to content width)* - it was large thin font that seemed to have a space between every letter. If I did **`ctrl`+`+`/`-`** it would fix it for the terminal in question, but if I had multiple terminal instances open and switched between them it would reset. The second I added `"terminal.integrated.fontFamily": "roboto mono"` it fixed it  immediately and permanently for all instances of the integrated terminal.