# VScode arabic font

Tags: visual-studio-code

in Ubuntu, the font of terminal is very different than it in windows and Arabic font look strange , so if you have a solution for this problem please tell me.

[my vscode window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EQQDf.png)

i want find a solution and learn about problems the people have it in technology

Comment: ... Is your question just "How to change font in VSCode?"

Comment: vscode *terminal* and also CLion *terminal* are not really good terminals (they are just a quick simple console for developers). So check with real terminal (and some minor terminal doesn't have all supports for Arabic). Still multilingual support on Linux terminal (and I assume in all others) is not a full solved problem (especially in cursive languages).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does my terminal in VS Code have weird spacing and how can I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70856163/why-does-my-terminal-in-vs-code-have-weird-spacing-and-how-can-i-fix-it)

Comment: There is also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66910984/my-terminal-is-acting-weird-in-vs-code-there-is-a-space-between-every-character